# SQL terminology to combine a NOT EXIST query with latest value

Tags: sql

I am a beginner with basic knowledge. 
I have a single table that I am trying to pull all UID's that have not had a particular code in the table within the past year.

My table looks like this: (but much larger of course)

```
FACID   DPID    EID DID UID DT  Code    Units   Charge  ET  Ord
1   1   6   2   1002    15-Mar-07   99204   1   180 09:36.7 1
1   1   7   5   10004   15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  02:36.9 1
1   1   24  55  25887   15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  43:55.3 1
1   1   25  2   355688  15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  53:20.2 1
1   1   26  5   555654  15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  42:22.6 1
1   1   27  44  135514  15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  00:36.8 1
1   1   28  2   3244522 15-Mar-07   99214   1   98  34:59.4 1
1   1   29  5   235445  15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  56:42.1 1
1   1   30  3   3214444 15-Mar-07   99213   1   68  54:56.5 1
1   1   33  1   221444  15-Mar-07   99204   1   180 37:44.5 1
```

I am attempting to use the following, but this is not working for my time frame limits.

```
select distinct UID from PtProcTbl
 where DT<'20120101'
 and NOT EXISTS (Select Distinct UID
                  where Code in ('99203','99204','99205','99213',
                                 '99214','99215','99244','99245'))
```

I need to know how to make sure the UID's that I am pulling are the ones don't have a DT after the 1/1/2012 cut off date that contains one of the NOT Exists codes.
The above query returned UID's that actually dates after 1/1/2012 that does contain one of the above codes...

Not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am totally off base on this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the `NOT EXISTS`? How about instead:
`AND Code NOT IN ('99203','99204','99205','99213','99214','99215','99244','99245')`